# How to change font color in QDateTimeEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I use QDateTimeEdit widget and QCheckBox. I want to change color of QDateTimeEdit's font depends whether checkbox is selected. I can't find function to set font color.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the text there are the following options depending on the style you use:

```cpp
QPalette pal = w.palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor("#00ff00"));
w.setPalette(pal)
```

Or

```
w.setStyleSheet("color: #00ff00");
```